# Infinitely many primes for quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $a \in \mathbb{N}.$ Prove there are infinitely many primes $p$ satisfying
$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) =1.$$

Remark: One may need to use the Dirichlet theorem, which states that if $a,m$ are coprime then there exists infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p \equiv a \pmod{m}.$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019538

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need Dirichlet's theorem. The following more general result is true.

**Proposition:** Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial with nonzero constant term. Then there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p | f(n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

To get the desired result take $f(x) = x^2 - a$.

*Proof 1.* Euler's proof of the infinitude of the primes carries over to this result. Certainly there exists at least one such prime. If $p_1, ... p_n$ are a finite collection of such primes, then $\frac{f(k f(0) p_1 ... p_n))}{f(0)}$ is relatively prime to each $p_i$ for any $k$, so for sufficiently large $k$ it has a prime divisor not among the $p_i$.

*Proof 2.* More generally we can replace $f(n)$ by a sequence which grows at most polynomially. See http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/some-remarks-on-the-infinitude-of-primes/.