# $n^2+an+b$ has at least 2018 prime divisors

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

> Prove that for every integer $a, b$ there exists an integer $n$ so that the number $n^2+an+b$ has at least 2018 prime divisors

I tried:

- Factoring the number $n^2+an+b = n(n+a) +b$
- Considering the sequence ${P_n}$ of all primes in increasing order

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem. But I need to ask whether this might be from some contest? You see, contest questions often use the year as an input in question (sometimes the exact year is crucial, sometimes a mild congruence condition would be ok, sometimes the parameter is a red herring). AND we have a strict policy not to allow questions from on-going contests.

Comment: If not from a contest then you probably should give a bit of other context. What pieces of theory have been covered recently? Chinese remainder theorem? Quadratic residues? Reciprocity law?

Comment: In questions like this I first use the brute force solution to get a feel for the problem and then try to derive a more efficient solution.

Comment: The contest has already ended, I was not part of it. But my friends wouldn't let me know the answer to it. All I know is I can use ALL arithmetic theorems

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I know the **Chinese remainder theorem**.

Comment: @MathBuster I was in the middle of typing a hint on how to use the Chinese remainder theorem when an answer was posted, so I abandoned the hint.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that $p$ is an odd prime, the equation
$$ n^2+an+b \equiv 0\pmod{p} $$ 
has at least a solution $n\equiv c_p\pmod{p}$ as soon as $a^2-4b$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$.
$a^2-4b$ is a quadratic residue for infinite$^{(*)}$ primes $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ and the system
$$ n\equiv c_{p_1}\!\!\!\pmod{p_1},\quad \ldots,\quad n\equiv c_{p_{2018}}\!\!\!\pmod{p_{2018}} $$
has an integer solution by the Chinese remainder theorem. 
A slight generalization is that $\omega(\text{monic quadratic polynomial }(n))$ is unbounded.

$(*)$ This is not entirely trivial. Assume, by contradiction, that some integer $m$ is a quadratic residue only for a finite number of prime moduli, the largest of them being $p$. By Dirichlet's theorem there is a prime $Q\equiv 1\pmod{4m}$ such that $Q>p$. By quadratic reciprocity for Legendre/Jacobi symbols
$$ \left(\frac{m}{Q}\right)=\left(\frac{Q}{m}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)=1$$
hence $m$ is a quadratic residue for some prime $Q>p$, contradiction.

Comment: What does $\omega$ mean in this context?

Comment: @saulspatz: the number of distinct prime divisors.

Comment: The accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226563/infinitely-many-primes-for-quadratic-residues gives an elementary proof without Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: True, but Qiaochu Yuan's answer assumes $b\neq 0$. Not a big issue, indeed, since the case $b=0$  is trivial, and the same applies to the case $a^2-4b=\square$.

Comment: I think he means a proof that an integer is a quadratic residue modulo infinitely many primes.